# regex to split string like "ABC123XYZ111" in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string  like **ABC123XYZ111** so that regex should be able to split last numeric part as one part and from starting to start of last numberic value si one part,
eg : I want to split into two parts 
first part should contain **ABC123XYZ** and 
second part should be **111**

first part may contain numeric values but second part should be numeric.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bC9qY5/2

Comment: I don't know regex, by google it I got this regex "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)")" but it's not suitable to my requirement. I have to do some customization with this regex, but I want exact regex to split as per my requirement,

Comment: I would suggest that if you don't know regular expressions but you want to *use* regular expressions, that you first *learn* regular expressions - at least the basics. Otherwise as soon as you want anything even slightly different, you'll be stuck again.

Comment: it'll take more time, but I need immediately,

Comment: As in the accepted answer: `String tok[] = str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d+\\b)");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple then.

```
String root = s.replaceAll("^(.*?)(\\d+)$", "$1");
String number = s.replaceAll("^(.*?)(\\d+)$", "$2");

^(.*?)(\\d+)$
^ = begin of string
$ = end of string
.*? = shortest sequence of any character
\d+ = digit, one or more
( ... ) = group numbered from 1, $1, $2, ...
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
myString.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
```

Comment: it is splitting my string "ABC123XYZ111" into ABC   123   XYZ  111 but I want like ABC123XYZ    111

Comment: Then why don't you save it as String `Array` and grab up the last element ?

Comment: This answer is a copy of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36364484/3832970). Well, little explanation is provided here and there...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't know where it exists but, I've once used it, So that I am posting it from that old project. I am sorry if I violated some standards.

Comment: I tried but my reviewer don't agree to that customization

Comment: Why don't they agree with that, even after you showed your output ?

Comment: I tried like this
String s = "ABC123XYZ111"
String[] split = s.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
Long number = Long.valueOf(split[split.length - 1]);
String[] copyOf = Arrays.copyOf(split, split.length - 1);
String newString = String.join("", copyOf);

Comment: @Sivakumar: Forget about this solution, use the one I linked to.

Comment: @Sivakumar what are you trying to do with  `String.join()`. It seems to be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `regex`

```
(.*?)(?=\d+$)(.*)
```

*Java Code*

```
String line = "ABC123XYZ111";
String pattern = "(.*?)(?=\\d+$)(.*)";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

if (m.find()) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
}
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/1tmq9c)**